# HTTP ERROR 405 when deploying React frontend with Spring boot REST API backend

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, heroku

I have developed a Spring boot REST API backend and React frontend, wanted to deploy to heroku cloud, but failed a zillion times.

##### Backend Controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping(
        path = "/api/auth",
        consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE },
        produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }
)
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@Autowired))
public class UserRegisterRestController {

    private final AppUserRoleRepository roleRepository;

    private final AppUserRepository userRepository;

    private final EmailService emailService;


    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(
            @Valid @RequestBody UserSignupRequest signUpRequestUser,
            HttpServletRequest request
    ) throws AuthenticationFailedException {

        // Some logic goes here
    }

    // Other endpoints skipped for brevity ;-)
    
}
```

##### Frontend React Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const UserSignup = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    reset,
    trigger,
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    const { name, email, age, address, contact, city, gender, role } = data;
    console.log(data);
    reset();
    console.log(name, ", ", email);
    try {
      const res = await fetch("/auth/signup", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: name,
          gender: gender,
          email: email,
          age: age,
          contact: contact,
          address: address,
          city: city,
          role: [role],
        }),
      });

      const res_data = await res.json();
      console.log("responsedata => ", res_data);

    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
       // Some HTML elements/other stuff goes here
    </>
  );
};

export default UserSignup;
```

##### Frontend React package.json:

```
{
  "name": "somegreatproject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "https://somegreatproject.herokuapp.com/api",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.20.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "start": "^5.1.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

##### Frontend React build files:

[image: react files generated after build]

##### Frontend React build files placed in Backend projects static folder/directory:

[image: Backend projects static folder/directory]

Okay, at this at when the project is deployed to heroku and I visit the link for example:

```
https://somegreatproject.herokuapp.com/api/auth/signup
```

it shows:

[image: HTTP ERROR 405 page]

Question is is some step missing in my build process? or is there any issue with react proxy and components fetch uri/url? kindly help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```js
const res = await fetch("/auth/signup", {...}
```

to

```js
const res = await fetch("/api/auth/signup", {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I have added `api` in `"proxy": "https://somegreatproject.herokuapp.com/api"` already in `package.json` file.

Comment: You need to post your proxy config here too

Comment: And also `405` happens when you try to request an endpoint that doesn't exist

Comment: I have added everything related in `package.json` above, please review it if you can!!

Comment: Isn't that the url of your frontend app?

Comment: I think you are trying to reach an API service whose URL is different that your frontend url

Comment: where is your backend is deployed and what's is the URL of it?

Comment: May I tell you privately in chat if you don't mind??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240404/discussion-between-ata-and-arshad-ali).